# how to create a PDF file uing javascript in IE

Tags: javascript

I want to create a PDF file based on users' query result (in html table).
What is the best javascript/lib I can use for IE?
I found jsPDF but it does not support IE.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no support for PDF.Instead if u want to convert the HTML page you are into you can try [PDF4ML](http://www.pd4ml.com/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think it was possible to create a PDF entirely in client-side JavaScript.  I would imagine any "JavaScript" examples out there use both JS and a server-side language.  In the past, I've used the active PDF API with C#.

Comment: Aye. Just read through the code (http://jspdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jspdf.js) looks to me as if the lib is printing out PDF syntax and FireFox ignores the doc-type and/or content-encoding... A shame IE doesn't